# 'angular2-text-mask' is not compatible with Angular Ivy

Tags: angular

I first upgraded my Angular project from v14 to v16 and received these errors, then I upgraded it to v17 in case it would be resolved, but the error persists. My '`package.json`' file is as follows, everything is up to date.

'`package.json`':

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build-production": "ng build --configuration=production --output-hashing=all",
    "test-local": "ng test --browsers Chrome",
    "test-production": "ng test --browsers ChromiumNoSandbox --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "analyze": "ng build --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/riverside-portal/stats-es5.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.7",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.2.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "bn-ng-idle": "^2.0.5",
    "jw-paginate": "^1.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mrz": "^3.4.1",
    "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^16.0.4",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^7.1.2",
    "ngx-mask": "^17.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.13",
    "@types/mrz": "^3.1.5",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.4",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.2",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.10.1"
  }
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

***This likely means that the library (angular2-text-mask) which declares TextMaskModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library
is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.***

I tried some solutions here and they didn't work. Solutions I tried:

1. Adding 'peerDependencies';    "peerDependencies":  {
   "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0"     }
2. Add 'postinstall' "scripts": {
   "postinstall": "ngcc"    }
3. "scripts": {            ...
   "postinstall": "npx --package @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.9 --yes ngcc",
   ...
   }

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm thinking I might need to find a compatible fork, since this hasn't been updated in 6 years

Comment: Even though the error showed like this, the reason was related to the other packages not being updated. When I updated the other packages, the problem was solved.

Comment: I ended up having to ditch angular2-text-mask and switched to maskito.